# Deploying Spring Project on Amazon EC2

Tags: spring, angularjs, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working on a project which involves Spring, AngularJS and MongoDB.

However, I want to deploy it on Amazon EC2.

***I did my basic homework by searching*** and couldn't really find any satisfying solutions.

**Question: Can I deploy my Spring MVC, AngularJS and MongoDB project on Amazon EC2?** or **do you have any good suggestable solutions to showcase my project?**

Thank you

Comment: EC2 is not much different than any other hosting environment, yes you can deploy your app on ec2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can deploy any thing to EC2 of AWS because EC2 is a virtual machine, run with OS Server (ubuntu, debian, winServer,...)

Make sure you install MongoDB engine, Web Container,... for what you want to run